# expl3 / setlength not working in preamble with expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3, preamble, function

I am writing a package that should output typographic sizes. For example the absolute character height, the x height, average character width,...
These should be available in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{expl3} % load latex3 packages
\usepackage{xparse}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Droid Sans Mono}

\newlength{\totalheight}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_typo_height_chars_tl {HIyjqpg}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \typo_set_totalheight:Nn #1#2 {
    \group_begin:
        \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 \c_typo_height_chars_tl }
        \exp_args:NNNe
    \group_end:
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \dim_eval:n { \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box } }
}
\exp_args_generate:n {NNe}


\typo_set_totalheight:Nn \totalheight {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\the\totalheight
\end{document}
```

But I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: No font usage before `\begin{document}`! Put your box assignment inside the begin document hook.

Comment: Doesn't `\typo_set_totalheight:Nn` take two arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `\typo_set_totalheight:Nn` with two arguments, but supply only one and TeX fetches `\ExplSyntaxOff` as the second argument. Chaos ensues.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newlength{\totalheight}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_typo_height_chars_tl {HIyjqpg}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \typo_set_totalheight:Nn #1#2 {
    \group_begin:
        \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 \c_typo_height_chars_tl }
        \exp_args:NNNe
    \group_end:
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \dim_eval:n { \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box } }
}
\exp_args_generate:n { NNe }

\AtBeginDocument{\typo_set_totalheight:Nn \totalheight {} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\the\totalheight
\end{document}
```

No need to load `expl3` and `xparse` with a recent LaTeX release. I'd not use `\vbox_set:Nn` but `\hbox_set:Nn`. And you need to generate `\exp_args:NNNe`.

It's best to do the setting at begin document, because the `\normalfont` is not really known in the preamble.

Comment: I tried giving it an extra argument, still gave the same error

Comment: @daleif the `\everypar` hook will fire inside the `\vbox` I guess, and that's the reason for the error.

Comment: Still, rule of thumb: You need a font, you use it after `\begin{document}` or inside a hook.

Comment: I tried loading it after setting the \mainfont but still the same error.
I tried with extra argument and also rewrote the function for one argument only. - still the same error.
I think it is an issue with the box.

Comment: It works if I call the function after \begin{document} but that would be too late. I need the lengths in the preamble to set geometry

Comment: @alexBer As far as I know, you can set also the parameters of `geometry` at begin document with `\newgeometry`.

Comment: @alexBer do you mean you got an error with egreg's code (which uses hbox) or with your original which uses vbox, so will trigger a missing document error?

Comment: With my vbox code

Comment: @alexBer You *can't* typeset paragraphs in the preamble and the vbox does.

Comment: OK, but is there another way to get the height and width of chars inside the preamble?

Comment: @alexBer Simple answer: no. Not one that is independent of every font package you can think of.